# Is there a way to add docker containers running on EC2 to ECS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs

Just checking if there is a way to add current docker containers running on a EC2 instance to ECS?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no way to do that. You would need to redeploy the containers as ECS tasks.